# Problems creating registry key

Tags: .net, registry

After searching for quite some time I have been unable to solve this problem.  I am trying to create a registry key in windows 7.  i have UAC off and have changed permissions and owner in the registry but I still get Access denied error.  I have pasted the code below.  I have tried several (even Microsofts) solutions to no avail.  Any help appreciated!

```
 Dim rs As RegistrySecurity = New RegistrySecurity()
    rs.AddAccessRule(New RegistryAccessRule(user, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))

    Dim subkey As String = "software\HSC\Extractor 3"
    Dim regkey As RegistryKey = LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryOptions.Volatile,rs)
    rs.AddAccessRule(New RegistryAccessRule(user, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow))
    regkey.SetAccessControl(rs)
    regkey = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl)
    rs.SetOwner(New NTAccount(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Should software in `software\HSC\Extractor 3' not be written in uppercase?